# Rerun failing cucumber tests from the cucumber.yml profile

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber

I am trying to create a profile in the cucumber.yml that reruns failed tests automatically. 
From the command line, I have been using this:
`cucumber tests -f pretty -f rerun --out rerun.txt || cucumber @rerun.txt`

Which works as expected running tests and then re-running the failing ones in rerun.txt

I created a profile in my cucumber.yml file 
`default: ENVIRONMENT=test BROWSER=chrome -f pretty -f rerun --out rerun.txt || cucumber @rerun.txt`

This works to a degree that it creates a rerun.txt file, populating it with failures but doesn't rerun. Which points towards `||` as the problem.

Found this https://gist.github.com/mattscilipoti/2882391

Which led me to try declaring
`<%
rerun = "-f pretty -f rerun --out rerun.txt || cucumber @rerun.txt"
%>`
in my cucumber.yml

Then using
`default: ENVIRONMENT=test BROWSER=chrome <% rerun %>`

However, this still isn't doing the re-run...
Can anyone help in pointing me in the right direction to fix this issue?

Comment: Anything on this? Did you fix the issue?

Comment: Never fixed it - I left the role and found another way to do what I needed before that.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I believe you need to explicitly call the profile you want to rerun the tests against.

```
-f pretty -f rerun --out rerun.txt || cucumber -p default @rerun.txt
```